# Publishing large papers

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I recently came across this query on a LinkedIn group. The exact query was:
"Does anyone know if there are journals in image/signal processing, CV or related ares, which have no page limitation and have ok/reasonable reputation? I have a theoretical paper which has 50 page."

Online journals could theoretically have no page limits but they still end up having limits/bounds. Why is it so?

Are there any such journals which allow for publishing of large sized papers?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you specified the concrete area. Off the top of my head, there's Annals of Physics, see, for example [52 pages](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1016/j.aop.2010.10.006) or [58 pages](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1016/j.aop.2012.06.005).

Comment: In mathematics, it is not rare to see very long papers with about or more than 100 pages.

Comment: Some journals will make exceptions to the usual rules under special circumstances. For instance, Physical Review D devotes an entire *volume* to the *Particle Data Book* every few years. Obviously such arrangements must be negotiated with the editors. And you have to have something pretty special to offer the journal to get that kind of treatment.

Answer (score 2):

For a long theory paper in image/signal processing, you could try [IEEE Transactions on Information Theory](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=18). The papers typically run about 20 pages, but [this classic](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=57199&punumber=18) runs 45 pages. Note that the two-column format can condense a one-column draft by 25% or more.

Trans IT is a very well-regarded journal in my field, with regular contributions from math-y engineers, statisticians, and engineer-y mathematicians.  To quote the aims and scope (emphasis mine):

> The IEEE Transactions on Information Theory publishes papers concerned with the transmission, processing, and utilization of information. While the boundaries of acceptable subject matter are intentionally not sharply delimited, its scope currently includes Shannon theory, coding theory and techniques, data compression, sequences, **signal processing**, detection and estimation, pattern recognition, learning and inference, communications and communication networks, complexity and cryptography, and quantum information theory and coding. IEEE Transactions on Information Theory papers **normally contain a strong conceptual and/or analytical contribution.**

The "strong conceptual and/or analytical contribution" means theorems and proofs; don't submit here if your paper doesn't have these. I couldn't find any stated page limit, but if your work is unnecessarily long for its contribution, the reviewers will definitely complain.

Another option is the [SIAM Journal on Imaging Science](http://www.siam.org/journals/siims/policy.php).  There is no hard-and-fast page limit there, but the policies do state that "papers exceeding 30 journal pages, excluding the supplementary material, will be reviewed more closely to ensure that the excess is fully justified."

For both of these journals, expect a very rigorous review cycle.  I suspect that, unless the results are earth-shattering, you will still hear complaints about the length.

Comment: Thanks for specific replies to the question. I will forward these results to him. I would appreciate other advice on how to deal with this kind of an issue as well.

Comment: The best bet for dealing with this issue is to shorten the paper. If its only good enough for a mid-range journal, then it probably isn't worth 50+ pages. Cut anything extraneous (extensions, refinements, etc.) and leave only the core contribution.

Answer (score 1):

In biology there are some journals that allow very long papers. These journals are typically online-only.

One example of such a journal is Biology Direct: [here](http://www.biologydirect.com/content/pdf/1745-6150-5-7.pdf) is an example with 78 pages. I remember seeing a 200-page paper in Biology Direct, but can't find it right now.

I wonder what the motivation is for someone to publish such long papers in this manner.

Comment: I guess the motivation is that what you want to achieve needs that many pages.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I can see this for a math or physics paper where you have very long proofs, but I don't think this is the case for these biology papers. They are written in a different style. For example, the paper which I linked to gives a 15 page introduction. This is very unconventional for a biological paper.